# Cutting continous variable into catagories ( ValueError: Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges)

Tags: python, pandas, cut, data-wrangling

I have a data column that I want to cut into discrete bins. My `min` is 1 and `max` is 70

```
df.total_value.describe()
count       37926.000000
mean        12.368138
std          7.385642
min          1.000000
25%          8.000000
50%         10.000000
75%         16.000000
max         70.000000
Name: total_value, dtype: float64
```

I tried this

```
labels = ["{0} - {1}".format(i, i + 1) for i in range(1, 70, 1)]

cut_bins = range(1, 70)
df['total_value_bins'] = pd.cut(df['total_value'], bins= cut_bins, labels=labels)
```

I get this error

```
ValueError: Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges
```

I was able to get the bins if I use

```
df['total_value_bins'] = pd.cut(df['total_value'], bins= cut_bins)
```

But I want to have nicely formated `e.g. 1-2`

Any suggestions help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you need to have `len(cut_bins) = len(labels)+1` while right now they are the same length. Moreover to be able to bin the values 1 and 70, you need to change the upper bound in the `range` of `cut_bins` to 71 (because the upper bound is in not created in the `range`), and use the parameter `include_lowest` in `cut`

```
labels = ["{0} - {1}".format(i, i + 1) for i in range(1, 70, 1)]

cut_bins = range(1, 71) # here goes to 71

# dummy data
s = pd.Series([1,4,45,70])

print(pd.cut(s, bins= cut_bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True))
0      1 - 2
1      3 - 4
2    44 - 45
3    69 - 70
dtype: category
Categories (69, object): ['1 - 2' < '2 - 3' < '3 - 4' < '4 - 5' ... '66 - 67' < '67 - 68' < '68 - 69' < '69 - 70']
```